# How can I make a bridge ethernet-wlan on Ubuntu server 18.04 (on raspberry Pi)?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, bridge, wifi, access-point

I would like to make a bridge between eth and wlan on my raspberry pi, which has Ubuntu server O.S.
I made this on Raspbian, so I guess it is possible. The idea is to get the information from some devices (sensors, mainly) through ethernet, and use the raspberry as an access point to get the sensors data from another PC via wi-fi. So the schema would be:

|Sensor Devices|  ---- eth ---->  |Raspberry Pi (Ubuntu)|  ---- wlan ---->  |PC|

How could I do this?
Thank you